# Vue: Why does Vuetify's <v-dialog> @update:model-value event only fire when the v-model's value is false?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

Please consider the following Vue 3 code which uses Vuetify 3.4.2:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-text-field v-model="msg" />
    </v-container>
    <v-btn @click="showDialog=true">Click</v-btn>
    <v-dialog v-model="showDialog" @update:model-value="handle"
      >Dialog</v-dialog
    >
  </v-app>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'

  const msg = ref('Hello World!')
  const showDialog = ref(false)
  const handle = newValue => {
    msg.value = newValue
  }
</script>
```

There's a [Vuetify Play playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNplUMFOhDAQ/ZWxFzQRSFwPZgNkjR78Aj2IhwrDLrG0TVtYE8K/O213A4mndua9N/PefM7MmiZ/1jqbRmR7VjgctOAOq1oCFFPKtQ7fUDRKOt5LNJdWaDr8dWnXo2hhSgfVoihrNthjzSC/SvP/WlJ+OwmHRvTNDynsSZ1fey7UsXRmxJpVLx7xUuKtojZwNqtWIW08jLol9/sAphMXIxLlxGUraOTVdRX5fnYcF4GYmZoxdJFvjkGlbUyvHVh0Y7xJP2hlHMxgsIMFOqMGSOiOiacDUGLrgC4BpWfcJm8ohIIPZUR7k9ytlDXBhdlxYXFDiP4JlHh+95mgrGCOpml+FnJuYI8sPkC0TGbZcs922S57Yv59zB7Y1x817KZf) to try it out.

When I click the `<v-btn>` button the `<v-dialog>` dialog is shown - indicating that the value of `showDialog` has changed to `true`. However, the text in the `<v-text-field>` does not change to `true`. It's as if the `handle()` function is not called.

When I click outside the dialog it becomes hidden, the `handle()` function is called and the text in `<v-text-field>` changes to `false` - as expected.

Why is `handle()` not called when the `<v-dialog>` model changes to `true`? How can I change the code to trigger the function when the `<v-dialog>` becomes visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update:model-value` is the event that VDialog emits when the change is made *from within VDialog*.  When you set `showDialog` to true in the parent, that value is passed down to the `modelValue` prop. The prop value in VDialog  updating does not itself trigger an emit.  It's also not needed.  If the parent changes the v-model value, the parent doesn't need an emit from the child to know it did that.

What you want in this situation is a [watcher](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html)

```js
import { watch } from 'vue'
...
watch(showDialog, newValue => {
  msg.value = newValue.toString()
})
```

[updated Vue Playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNplkMFOhDAQhl9l7IU12YXE9WAMbDR68G6iB/FQYdhtLLRpB9aE8O5O6Sqb7AU60//r9OvHKLyrskdr06FHcS9ywtZqSbgrO4B82Ehr5+VcVKYjqTp0p9bcJPyhTaNQ1zBsWlOjLkrR+n0pIPtDs0uWyS/q4KHSqvpmwh/M8VlJbfYFuR5LsXsKOwHl3ALVc+Zs1AIyExcBirmowWX0yLMzPy595ZQl8Eh91FStNY5gBIfNGo6SqgNM0DjTQsIvlAQKgF08ATtCEYKr5AW1NvBunK6vkuslstztlGyk9siBEJlPXy2RNXR4fJO6Ryh2MEZjHpIOsfe/nZJ5Jae6/WoeNfE3z6IKS4hpLbbpNr0T4X+b3ojPXwxwoQk=)